# What is the meaning/translation of a MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

For an instance : 00:0a:95:9d:68:16
I wonder if 00, 0a, 68 or 16 etc, has some specific meaning or can be translated, like giving the vendor information, date of issuing etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first 3 bytes or 24 bits is the Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI), which uniquely identifies a vendor, manufacturer, or other organization.

```
00:0a:95
```

The last 3 bytes or 24 bits is the network interface identifier. This can be anything the vendor or manufacturer wants it to be as long as it complies with the MAC address construct.

```
9d:68:16
```

Comment: is there an official link, where everyone can check that meaning ?

Comment: No offense, but have you even tried to google it?

Comment: https://aruljohn.com/mac.pl

Comment: Yes or https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/OUI.html